# Python craps game: Wrong output

Tags: python

> I'm a beginner and I can't figure out why I can't get the output I
> want. It's a craps game. It's suppose to go like:
>
> How many games do you want to play > 6 You rolled  5  +  2  =  7 You
> win
>
> What I got is something like: You rolled 1 + 6 = 7 You rolled 1 + 6 =
> 7 You rolled 1 + 6 = 7 You lose

```
import random


def rollDice():
  roll_1 = random.randint(1,7)
  roll_2 = random.randint(1,7)
  return roll_1, roll_2

def determine_win_or_lose(dice1,dice2):
  sum = dice1 + dice2
  print("You rolled", dice1, "+", dice2, "=", sum )
  if sum == '2' or '3' or '12':
    return 0
  elif sum == '7' or '11':
    return 1
  else:
    print("Point is", sum)
    determinePointValueResult(sum)
    if determinePointValueResult(sum) == 1:
      return 1
    elif determinePointValueResult(sum) == 0:
      return 0
  

def determinePointValueResult(sum):
  point = sum
  while sum != 7 and sum != point:
    x, y = rollDice()
    sum = x + y
    if sum == point:
      return 1
    elif sum == '7':
      return 0
    print("You rolled", x, "+", y, "=", sum )
 

#==== MAIN =====
win = 0
lose = 0

game = int(input("How many games do you want to play > "))

for i in range(game): 
  x, y = rollDice()
  determine_win_or_lose(x, y)
  if determine_win_or_lose(x, y) == 1:
    print("You win")
    win = win + 1
  elif determine_win_or_lose(x, y) == 0:
    print("You lose")
    lose = lose + 1

print("Game results: ", win, "wins and", lose, "losses")
```

Comment: This kind of code `if sum == '2' or '3' or '12':` does not work like you think it should. See [Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True? How can I compare "a" to all of those?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al)

Comment: You call `determine_win_or_lose()` two or three times per game; each call will result in the "You rolled..." message being printed.  Call it *once*, and save the result in a variable so you don't need to call it again.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious issues:

1. You call `determine_win_or_lose` too many times in your `for` loop.  Change it to:

```
for i in range(game): 
  x, y = rollDice()
  result = determine_win_or_lose(x, y)
  if result == 1:
    print("You win")
    win = win + 1
  elif result == 0:
    print("You lose")
    lose = lose + 1
```

2. Your check in `determine_win_or_lose` is incorrect.  It should be something like:

```
def determine_win_or_lose(dice1,dice2):
  sum = dice1 + dice2
  print("You rolled", dice1, "+", dice2, "=", sum )
  if sum == 2 or sum == 3 or sum == 12:
    return 0
  elif sum == 7 or sum == 11:
    return 1
  else:
    print("Point is", sum)
    determinePointValueResult(sum)
    if determinePointValueResult(sum) == 1:
      return 1
    elif determinePointValueResult(sum) == 0:
      return 0
```

3. In `determinePointValueResult` you shouldn't compare `sum` to a string, but an integer:

```
def determinePointValueResult(sum):
  point = sum
  while sum != 7 and sum != point:
    x, y = rollDice()
    sum = x + y
    if sum == point:
      return 1
    elif sum == 7:
      return 0
    print("You rolled", x, "+", y, "=", sum )
```

4. It's possible that `determine_win_or_lose` and `determinePointValueResult` are `return`ing `None`.  You may need to change your `elif`s to `else`s or create a new `else` case.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue come from the main, because you call the `determine_win_or_lose` function 3 times, the first one before the if (and i'm not sure why since you do nothing with it), a second time to check the condition of the if and a third time to check the condition of the elif.

Since it's this function that print the message, and you call the function 33 times each iteration of the for loop, it's normal to get the message printed 3 times.

(
Also since the `determine_win_or_lose` will always return 0 or 1 you don't really need an elif you can just do an if/else to achieve the same thing and simplify your code a bit.
)

So i'd suggest the following  :

```py
#==== MAIN =====
win = 0
lose = 0

game = int(input("How many games do you want to play > "))

for i in range(game): 
  x, y = rollDice()
  result = determine_win_or_lose(x, y)
  if result == 1:
    print("You win")
    win = win + 1
  else:
    print("You lose")
    lose = lose + 1

print("Game results: ", win, "wins and", lose, "losses")
```